# EF5 code first enum support - define the enum inside the entity

Tags: .net, entity-framework, enums, code-first

Funny question..

I have a type that has a Status field. For my convenience and order of things I want to define the enum for this status inside the Entity type:

```
public class User
{
  public enum Statuses
  {
     Active,
     Suspended
  }

  public int ID { get; set; }
  public Statuses Status { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason the Status property isn't mapped to the database.

Now the funny bit - if I take the enum definition out of User then it is mapped to the DB!

I know that the quick answer would be to leave it outside the class, but that would require me to give the enum a longer name UserStatuses or something like that, as now it isn't scoped inside User.

Did anyone encounter that issue? Is there a solution before I start compromising?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF5 only supports enums that are defined under a namepace. It doesn't support enums defined within a class or nested within another enum.

I don't know if it's the 'most correct' way of doing things, but I prefer to keep any enums in their own namespace ("Enums" or something similar) and give them more meaningful names (ie: UserStatus). An enum called "Statuses" is too generic, gets confusing once you've got half a dozen enum definitions floating around and could also result in namespace clashes when you get further into the application and have to add a status enum to other entities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess it's a matter of approach. Well, I will leave this question open a bit longer to see if I can somehow still do things "my way". If not then I guess your answer is the one!  :)